# Events are causing a chain reaction

Tags: java, events, swt

I'm using an Eclipse RCP based framework that suffers from an inefficient event model. Specifically, events emitted by controls often 'cascade'. For example, a control will emit a `COLOR_CHANGED` event causing the parent composite to propagate the event to sibling controls, which in turn, decide to emit their own `COLOR_CHANGED` events (in response to the original event), leading to a chain reaction of sorts. I've profiled the app raising over 100,000 events to render a simple form. Frankly, I don't understand how it's not overflowing the stack.

So, I'm looking for a technique or design pattern that prevents or reduces this kind of cascade behaviour. I've had a few ideas but this can't be a new problem; there's got to be a 'best practice' out there already for event-oriented design.

My ideas:

- Events operate like a stack-trace, so new events are chained to their cause. This enables listeners to ignore events that originated from themselves. However, this greatly complicates my event model (and it would be tedious to wrap standard SWT events). Not to mention there are valid use-cases where you might actually want this behaviour.
- A central 'event pump' is used to raise events. If an event has the same source and payload as a previously raised event within the last *n* milliseconds, it is discarded. This would hopefully have a doping effect and prevent the events from cascading. Obviously, I can't control how SWT/RCP events are raised but these aren't my main concern.
- Events should be typed. This seems like a step backwards but I think finer grained events would help performance. For example, `ValidationFailedEvent` rather than generic `Event` that everybody handles (and then has to interrogate it's state to determine the event type).

Thanks for taking the time to read about my problem. All advice/suggestions welcome.

**EDIT**: Thanks to pablosaraiva, I read about [Chain-of-responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and now have the following idea:

- Events expose an `isHandled` property which, if set to true, will prevent the event from propagating. This should work when the event's scope is understood but won't help if the event can not be 'handled' by a single control.

Comment: Have you looked at Chain of Responsibility?

Comment: @pablosaraiva: It looked promising, but I don't see how it will help in the case of 'one-to-many' events i.e. many controls need to receive the event.

Comment: You say it is "_an Eclipse RCP based framework_" - which should mean SWT - but I cannot the rest of the description with this. What framework do you mean?

Comment: @Tonny Madsen: Sorry, I'm not comfortable naming it as I don't want to identify my client. It's a very niche framework produced by a very large vendor. Unfortunately, the use of this framework is non-negotiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with lots of different approaches to this over the years. The fundamental thing you can do to fix this is to have models only emit events if they actually change. This makes models slightly more complicated for each class in the model, but it is the only way I've managed to make this paradigm work.

For example

```
public void setColor(Color c)
{
   setBackground(c);
   notify(new ColorChangedEvent(this, c));
}
```

would become

```
public void setColour(Color c)
{
    if (!getBackground().equals(c))
    {
       setBackground(c);
       notify(new ColorChangedEvent(this, c));
    }
}
```

The standard Observable classes in java support this with the 'setChanged()' method.

A slightly easier way of implementing this (but IMHO not as good) is to make 'notify' turn off listening until it has finished notifying. That is, notify looks like

```
private iAmNotifying;
public void notify(Event e) 
{ 
    if (!iAmNotifying)
    {
        iAmNotifying = true;
        doTheActualNotification(e);
        iAmNotifying = false;
    }
}
```

But this has some significant drawbacks in terms of granularity, and I've had better success with the first approach.

Comment: Both great suggestions. The only drawback I can envisage relates to the second snippet, which may become complex if events are raised asynchronously.